# Integrating CK Editor in Rails 3 through an iframe to avoid CSS clash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I used the following CK Editor gem https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor for rails to load CK Editor in Rails 3 but dialogs look weird because of a clash with the CSS of my application( I'm using Twitter Bootsrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ for my CSS). The biggest problems is that the CSS from Bootsrap changes the way input fields look by default and that shouldn't be the case for CK Editor dialogs.
The only way to avoid this problem, from my perspective, is to use CK Editor through an iframe but I can't find a tutorial for this and I don't know if it's possible. Does anybody know something about this or another solution?

Answer (score 0):

just found this theme:

https://github.com/Kunstmaan/BootstrapCK-Skin

at the time of writing, it's not updated to twitter bootstrap 2.0, so you might want to change some stuff inside this theme.